# Как создать миграцию в FastAPI?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Привет) Изучаю FastAPI и столкнулся с проблемой, не могу создать миграции, хотя вроде все делаю по документации

Вот в чем беда:

Моя модель

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

Получаю ошибку `ValueError: String is not true/false: 'true)'`.

Ок, меняю `__tablename__` на `__table__` получаю `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'`

Что не так делаю?

Comment: В FastAPI нет миграций/ORM и вообще доступа к базе и всего такого из коробки. Если используете ORM, то указывайте какую ORM используете, их значительно больше одной.

Comment: SQLAlchemy и alembic для миграций

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В SQLAlchemy есть файл `langhelpers.py` с методом `asbool`

Я закоментировал там практически все

```
def asbool(obj: Any) -> bool:
# if isinstance(obj, str):
#     obj = obj.strip().lower()
#     if obj in ["True", "yes", "on", "y", "t", "1"]:
#         return True
#     elif obj in ["false", "no", "off", "n", "f", "0"]:
#         return False
#     else:
#         raise ValueError("String is not true/false: %r" % obj)
  return bool(obj)
```

и случилось чудо, все миграции заработали. Посмотрим дальше, мб что то другое сломал)

Comment: У вас данные в базе были кривые

Comment: у меня вообще данных в базе не было) Я просто не мог сформировать миграцию

Comment: 'true)' - говорит что кривые данные

Comment: Да это я понял) Я только не пойму что за данные, таблица девственно чиста, в миграции 3 поля, что там может еще быть кривым?